Why only TrilistSelect component is not re-rendered even if form is re-rendered after another field , setted to live(), changes status?
I am trying to create dependant fields in Filament.Specifically, I want to make a TrilistSelect field
whose displayed data changes accordingly to selection of another Select field.
When an option is selected, live() triggers the re-render of form but Trilist component is not refreshed. How Can I solve ?
Here  a snippet of class used to create form and table.
class RulesRelationManager extends RelationManager

    protected static string $relationship = 'rules';



public function form(Form $form): Form
{


    return $form
        ->schema( [
            Forms\Components\Select::make('datasource_id')->label('source')



            ->relationship('datasource','name')

            ->required()->live(),


           //->default(3),



            TrilistSelect::make('path')->options(function (Get $get) {

                if($get('datasource_id') == null)
                    return [['id' => '55', 'label' => '55']];


                    return [['id' => $get('datasource_id'), 'label' => $get('datasource_id')]];


            }),


The code is incomplete. Please correct it and make sure it's a minimal, complete and verifiable example.
